# eslint for storybook mdx

Tags: eslint, storybook

I am setting up storybook for a project using .mdx format and I would like to set up eslint so that I can check for things like spaces, alphabetical ordering and other things.

I have tried to set up this https://github.com/mdx-js/eslint-mdx and it seems that I have, but when I run `eslint . --ext mdx`, I get the following errors in one of my stories.mdx files:

[image]

Could someone please point me to a good resource to solving this or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/mdx-js/eslint-mdx/issues/230#issuecomment-684138734) on their github page that fixed the issue for me. Basically we use "overrides" in .eslintrc to assign the correct parser to mdx files, like so:

```
{
  ...,
  overrides: [
    {
      files: '*.mdx',
      extends: 'plugin:mdx/recommended',
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: is it enough for working with `storybook`?